# How to have at least two datepickers of ui-bootstrap on a single page?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to have several datepickers on a page. But with the default solution from UI-Bootstrap it is not possible, no one of datepickers may be opened. The conflict with each other. Here is my code:

```
<div>
            <div class="form-horizontal pull-left">
                <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"/>
                <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-horizontal pull-left">
                <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" />
                <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

I just did a copy/paste of the datepicker code from the site http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker. They conflict with each other. When I click `<input>` field to open a datepicker no one can be opened properly, both are opened for a second and immediately disappear.

How may I have several datepickers on a single page?

Comment: You should probably assign them to different ng-models.

Comment: agree with @aet and also use a different `is-open` variable for each

Comment: Have you found solution? If yes, please describe it.

Comment: The solution is to use a different variable for the ```is-open``` attribute.  If you don't do that the ui-bootstrap stuff can't keep up with which one is open.  @Green should select one of the answers below as the accepted answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to usemultiple Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker in single form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269964/how-to-usemultiple-angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-in-single-form)

Answer (score 79):

Rather than using a different function you can use a different `is-open` attribute and then pass the attribute in through the `ng-click` function. You still need different models:

```
<div>
        <div class="form-horizontal pull-left">
            <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt1" is-open="opened1" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"/>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="open($event,'opened1')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-horizontal pull-left">
            <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt2" is-open="opened2" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" />
            <button class="btn" ng-click="open($event,'opened2')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

And inside controller:

```
   $scope.open = function($event,opened) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope[opened] = true;
  };
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, I didn't need to define my own open() method in the controller and this simply worked for me out of the box.

Comment: How can I do the same for whole application?

Comment: I'v changed to a toggle behaviour here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23764727/2411379

Comment: Dont use caps on `is-open` field

Comment: this actually did work for me. not sure what your angularjs is smokin @rar? what helped me was @Toni Gamez's link to the toggle function. No need to actually rename the function but it helped to see it simplified in the link he provides in the comments above...

Comment: "not sure what your angularjs is smokin" has been much of my experience with angular so far :)

Comment: This didn't work for me. This did though:

`<input type="text" 
id="startDate" 
ng-model="startDate" 
ng-click="start.opened = true" 
datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
is-open="start.opened" />`

Comment: Note for people who can't get this to work, make sure you have single quotes wrapped around opened, and opened2. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Works great here. Easily turned into a toggle as well with `$scope[opened] = !$scope[opened]`

Answer (score 15):

I'm still learning Angular and UI-Bootstrap, so take that into account when reading my answer.  I did something similar to BlueMonk, but in a flexible way that keeps my controller code from having to know about the instances of the datepicker on the page.

I put all of the datepicker code in my controller into a single namespace:

```
$scope.datePicker = (function () {
    var method = {};
    method.instances = [];

    method.open = function ($event, instance) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        method.instances[instance] = true;
    };

    method.options = {
        'show-weeks': false,
        startingDay: 0
    };

    var formats = ['MM/dd/yyyy', 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    method.format = formats[0];

    return method;
}());
```

And then used the following markup:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="editableEmployee.dateHired" datepicker-popup="{{datePicker.format}}" datepicker-options="datePicker.options" is-open="datePicker.instances['dateHired']" close-text="Close" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="datePicker.open($event, 'dateHired')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>

<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="editableEmployee.dateFired" datepicker-popup="{{datePicker.format}}" datepicker-options="datePicker.options" is-open="datePicker.instances['dateFired']" close-text="Close" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="datePicker.open($event, 'dateFired')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>
```

This worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Thank you very much and quite creative. :)

Comment: @JerryBensonMontgome my use case involves a dynamic set of rows that can grow (by clicking Add Another button), wherein one column corresponds to a date field that must be enriched by a datepicker. In that case, how do I use your elegant approach?

Comment: If you just pass in a custom string for each row (where I have 'dateHired' and 'dateFired') you should be fine.  I typically use some static text concatenated with some sort of row id when I do this type of thing.  Heck, a randomly generated number would work because I don't think you (as the developer) ever need to know what it is.  I haven't used this solution in a scenario like yours, but I think it should work.

Comment: This looks very elegant, but I get an undefined error on this line:  method.instances[instance] = true;

Comment: I've asked a follow-up question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927394/typeerror-undefined-on-module-pattern-of-object-instances

Answer (score 10):

This should work (different models, open flag, and functions):

```
<div>
        <div class="form-horizontal pull-left">
            <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt1" is-open="opened1" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"/>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="open1()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-horizontal pull-left">
            <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt2" is-open="opened2" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" />
            <button class="btn" ng-click="open2()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

And inside controller:

```
   $scope.open1 = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened1 = true;
  };

   $scope.open2 = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened2 = true;
  };
```

Comment: This should not work, and should throw 'preventDefault' of undefined. to solve the error you pass $event to your functions. It still wont solve the problem. As the two will still conflict. It didnt work for me.

Comment: This isn't very DRY. I prefer BlueMonk's answer.

Comment: This works. But you have to pass $event into `open1($event)` and `open2($event)` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:
$id is scope id, provided by angular.

```js
    ctrl.opened = {};
    ctrl.openDatatimePicker = function ($event, id) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        ctrl.opened[id] = true;
    }
```

```html
                                            <input type="text" 
                                                   class="form-control" 
                                                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{vm.datepickerFormat}}"
                                                   ng-model="x.FraDato" 
                                                   is-open="vm.opened[$id]"
                                                   datepicker-options="vm.datepickerOptions"
                                                   ng-required="true" 
                                                   ng-click="vm.openDatatimePicker($event,$id)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

No Additional changes are necessary. As long as you wrap each date input in it's own controller div the scope will reside with that input

Example:

```
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <div class="form-horizontal pull-left">
        <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"/>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="open($event)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <div class="form-horizontal pull-left">
        <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" />
        <button class="btn" ng-click="open($event)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually he does have to make changes, ng-model="dt" buried in another controller like that will be useless.  He needs to use ```something.startOn```, ```something.endOn``` so the variables are made available on the surrounding scope.  Otherwise this is a pretty cool trick with controllers.

Answer (score 0):

though its an old question but answring for someone who fall in to same problem as i did.

i assigned the datepicker onfocus to that element and it workd great.
Sample code.

```
   $(document).on('focus','.datepicker',function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can open multi datepickers of ui-bootstrap on a single page**

JS

```
  $scope.open = {};
  $scope.openCalendar = function (e, date) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if ($scope.open[date] === true) {
      $scope.open = {};
    } else {
      $scope.open = {};
      $scope.open[date] = true;
    }
  };
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="created1" name="created1" datetime-picker="" datepicker-options="dateOptions" timepicker-options="timeOptions" ng-click="openCalendar($event, 'created1')" placeholder="0000/00/00 00:00" is-open="open.created1" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.condition.created1">

<input type="text" id="created2" name="created2" datetime-picker="" datepicker-options="dateOptions" timepicker-options="timeOptions" ng-click="openCalendar($event, 'created2')" placeholder="0000/00/00 00:00" is-open="open.created2" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.condition.created2">
```