# Using datepicker on more than one input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following two input fields that use datepicker.

```
    <div class="row">  
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
  <div>

    <div class="row">         
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt2" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>       
    </div>
```

The controller code is

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.showWeeks = true;
  $scope.toggleWeeks = function () {
    $scope.showWeeks = ! $scope.showWeeks;
  };

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = ( $scope.minDate ) ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };


  $scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
};
```

Problem is whenever I click any button both datepicker calenders pop up. Here is the plunker for it 
http://plnkr.co/edit/hcLogY0SPsFzewcCt0xh?p=preview

Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269964/how-to-use-2-or-more-angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-in-1-form/22270255#22270255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your code with 2 ng-controllers.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Cp7ZlWl8Ee8TCAOnfxv2?p=preview