# How to display datepicker one at a time?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using datepicker from "http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/" 
In my page i am using more than one datepicker, So now i am able to open both at a time but what i exactly need is one datepicker at a time can any one suggest me an answer.

**Code**

```
   angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl',  
   function ($scope) {
   $scope.today = function() {
   $scope.dt = new Date();
   };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function () {
  $scope.dt = null;
  };

 // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
  return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) 
   );
 };

$scope.toggleMin = function() {
 $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
};
 $scope.toggleMin();

$scope.open = function($event) {
$event.preventDefault();
$event.stopPropagation();

$scope.opened = true;
 };

$scope.dateOptions = {
formatYear: 'yy',
startingDay: 1
};

$scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
});
```

Comment: can anyone answer for this question???????

Comment: Can you show your related HTML as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ee07j3b7/--- see this for html

Comment: did u see html?? @haxtbh

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use 2 or more Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker in 1 Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269964/how-to-use-2-or-more-angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-in-1-form)

Comment: i am very new to angular i am confused can u tell me little clearly? @haxtbh

Comment: Read the answer in the duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22270255/3535297. This will explain what he did to make it work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69301/discussion-between-manoji-stack-and-haxtbh).