# angular-ui datepicker popup showing morethan one time i need one at a time

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui

Hi All i am using angular ui datepicker, i am using 4 datepicker, i am now able to open all at same time. but i can be able to open one at a time[image: multiple datepicker opening but i need one at a time]

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-controller="approvalDate" class="datePickerClass">
   <p class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select date" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" input-disabled="editableInput"/>
       <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default calandar-custom" ng-click="open($event)" input-disabled="editableInput"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"> </i> </button>
       </span>  
      </span> 
    </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the same ng_model name foreach of the datepickers, you have to change that!!

Take a look here at "wayne"s answer (:

[How to usemultiple Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker in single form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269964/how-to-use-2-or-more-angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-in-1-form)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup ng-model="atime" is-open="atime_opened" ng-click="atime_opened = !atime_opened"/>
```