# Bootstrap Angular Datepicker is not working

Tags: angularjs, calendar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the code sample from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker when I tried to integrate it to the app there is no error in the developers console.

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
   $scope.status.opened = true;
};
```

html:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
           uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
           ng-model="PublishedDate" 
           is-open="status.opened" 
           show-weeks="true" 
           class="well well-sm" 
           custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)" 
           close-text="Close" /> 
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                ng-click="open($event)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

This method is executed in the controller and set the  `$scope.status.opened = true;` but calendar is not displayed. Can someone please say where I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you include your html for your datepicker?

Comment: <p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="PublishedDate"
                       is-open="status.opened"  show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"
                       close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>

            </p>

Comment: in $scope.open method, add `$event.stopPropagation()` and `$event.preventdefault()`, it might works... I have found same solution on many websites.

Answer (score 2):

js:

```
$scope.dt = new Date(); // will return a new date object with the current date and time
```

html:

```
<datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm"></datepicker>
```

Also remebember to initialize it in you your angular module:

```
angular.module('theNameOfYourAngularFormsApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: can i please know what is toDate in js

Comment: new Date(); will return a new date object with the current date and time. You can read more about the Date object [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same answer as [sjokkogutten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319839/sjokkogutten) above.

The ng-model for the uib-datepicker-popup needs to be set or initialized to aJavaScript Date object.

A string will not work :( make sure your controller looks like this

`$scope.PublishedDate  = new Date();`

All you need to know on how to initialize to a specific value https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Also check out this answer for more help. [How to usemultiple Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker in single form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269964/how-to-usemultiple-angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-in-single-form?rq=1)