# Datepicker not opening twice in angular-ui version 0.11.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to have 2 datepickers and I am using Angular UI version 0.11.0.

My HTML code

```
<span ng-if="periods.period == 10">
     <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="cdate.customStartDate" is-open="opened1"  max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" class="input-md" />
     <button class="btn" ng-click="open($event,'opened1')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>

</span>


<span ng-if="periods.period == 10"> 
- 
    <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="cdate.customEndDate" is-open="opened2"  min-date="cdate.customStartDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"  ng-required="true" close-text="Close" class="input-md" />
    <button class="btn" ng-click="open($event,'opened2')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>   
</span>
```

and my JS code is 
`

```
                     $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
                      return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === -1 || date.getDay() === 7 ) );
                     };

                     $scope.maxDate = new Date();


                       $scope.open = function($event,opened) {
                            $event.preventDefault();
                            $event.stopPropagation();

                            $scope[opened] = true;
                          };


                     $scope.dateOptions = {
                     'year-format': "'yy'",
                     'starting-day': 1
                     };
```

`
At first, when I click on the button, datepicker opens up just fine. But once it has been opened once,the problem is that the datepicker popup doesn't open the next time I click on the button.

Comment: I followed the method given here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613510/how-to-have-at-least-two-datepickers-of-ui-bootstrap-on-a-single-page

Comment: any output in the javascript console when you click the second time?

Comment: no, nothing in the console

Comment: to me it seems you are not showing the whole code, how do you actually open the datepicker itself?

Comment: <button class="btn" ng-click="open($event,'opened1')">

On clicking the button, the datepicker shows up.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Quick Fix: 
Removed the button tag altogether and modified the datepicker code, so it looks like this :

```
<input type="text" 
       datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"
       ng-model="cdate.customStartDate"
       is-open="cdate.customStartDate.open"
       ng-click = "cdate.customStartDate.open = true"
       max-date="maxDate"
       datepicker-options="dateOptions"
       date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
       ng-required="true"
       close-text="Close"
       class="input-md" />
```

Comment: Wonderful, this makes this directive so simple. I wonder why people need buttons to handle the date picker :P

Comment: It is important to highlight that moving the open flag "one level deeper", as answered by Exermel was what actually solved the issue.

Answer (score 55):

I was having the same issue whereby I could only open the date picker control once using the button, but it would not open a second time.  The problem may be related to a scope issue which might be coming about because the button is not a child of the input HTML element.  I was able to get the button to work by changing the data model a little bit.  For example, instead of using `$scope.isDatePickerOpen` as the model, I changed to `$scope.datePicker.isOpen` (and set `is-open="datePicker.isOpen"`).  Note that the new data model for is-open does not hang directly off of `$scope`, but was moved one level deep (off the `$scope.datePicker` object).  This seems to make the data more "findable".

The other thing I had to do was change the data model on a timer.  For example:

```
$scope.openDatePicker = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  $timeout( function(){
     $scope.datePicker.isOpen = true;  
  }, 50);
};
```

At any rate, your workaround posted above was what gave me the motivation to keep looking for a solution, so thanks!

Comment: Great, can you give a Plunk for your solution.

Comment: @AniketSinha http://plnkr.co/edit/NuoBQe?p=info. This happened to me in the modal window as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716113/scope-issue-in-angularjs-using-angularui-bootstrap-modal

Comment: It has to do with the data being a Primitive. They suggest to avoid primitives if possible (data that isnt part of an object). http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/

Comment: Worked for me. It is probably not the best solution, but it works for now. Also, remember to inject the $timeout service in the controller.

Comment: This worked for me. I tried the other suggestions, using $parent.isOpen, and it just didn't work for me (even though I saw plunks showing that adding $parent does in fact work). Frustrating.

Comment: It doesn't work so well for me. When I try to change the month it simply closes the datepicker.

Comment: Like you said, I created '$scope.opened = { yesOpen: false };' in my controller and this worked when using 'opened.yesOpen'  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Been working with this for hours, managed to get it to work without the extra timeout function.

Comment: I did the same workaround by changing `is_open` model one level deeper. And there's issue with `ng-model` binding as well, that if `ng-model="date"`, the model is not actually updated when date is picked, the workaround is also add one level to the model, eg. `ng-model="data.date"`.

Comment: They addressed [this kind of problems on their FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ#my-input-elements-stop-working-when-i-place-a-tooltip--popover-on-it). They only talk about the `ngModel` case, but it applies to several other cases, this being one. I confess I didn't thought about it either, 'till I saw this. Thanks!

Comment: Only had to add $timeout to get mine to work, thanks :)

Answer (score 31):

Found answer on other StackOverflow question, just use is-open="$parent.isOpen"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20213924/1596661

Comment: Spent many many hours trying to figure out why it works once and then isOpen is permanently false. And only if you put the thing in an ngIf. Thank you for this.

Comment: This answer only applies if the date-picker doesn't show up at all. OP can view the date-picker at first click but not the second.

Comment: USE  is-open="$parent.opened" AND ng-click="$parent.opened = true"

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, but by simply putting the "opened" boolean var in an object solved the problem for me:

```
< .. is-open="datePicker.opened" >
...
$scope.datePicker = {opened:false};
$scope.openDate = function($event) {
     $event.preventDefault();
     $event.stopPropagation();
     $scope.datePicker.opened = true;
};
```

I have not used angular for that long but I think this is scope problem and then I learned that it is always good to have "a dot in the variable name"... ( datePicker.opened )

(I now see a post above with a similar solution. But I did not need to use the timeout. This code was enough.)

Comment: this one solved the issue. $scope.opened ==> $scope.dataPic.did the trick

Comment: This is the real solution.Thx

Answer (score 11):

I solved the problem like this :

In the html file:

```
<input is-open="opened"
       type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
       ng-model="md" />
```

and in the Javascript file, i just added a timeout to 'notify' that it's closed in order to be able to open it again :

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.opened = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.opened = false;
        }, 10);              
    };
```

Comment: Its best to use $timeout from angular itself, its safer.

Comment: @jeveloper If you try to replace setTimeout with $timeout it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidePastore You need to inject $timeout into your controller. Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: Already done and when it opens it closes after 10 milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

I have the easiest, one-line solution that **does not require** container objects, function calls or other hassles like preventDefault. You don't even have to declare this in scope because undefined is evaluated as false.

```
...
  ng-click="dateOpened = !dateOpened"
...
```

I tested this with angular-ui 0.13.0 (Angular Bootstrap). This works because the invocation of ng-click is already trapping the default event.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by adding changing is-open from "opened" to "$parent.opened"
Like this.

```js
seanControllers.controller('TracksController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.openCalendar = function($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      $event.stopPropagation();

      $scope.opened = true;
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Eindtijd</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" ng-model="track.eindtijd" is-open="$parent.opened" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="openCalendar($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes. Thats how KCMonkey solved it too. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24700317/3214856

Answer (score 2):

Just isolate your dataPicker state variables.

```
$scope.dataPickerStates = {
  open1:false,
  open2:false
}
```

then change your html to

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="cdate.customStartDate" is-open="dataPickerStates.open1"  max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" class="input-md" />
```

and finally your state changer method

```
$scope.open = function($event, opened) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  $scope.datePickerStates[opened] = true;
};
```

that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem but the above solutions did not work for me, turns out I wasnt including this file: ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js.

Point is to make sure you are including all the files mentioned in the example documentation

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Well, I think you must have downloaded the js file without the templates. As you've mentioned, download the js with the templates i.e having `tpls` in it, if you are not planning to have your own templates.

Comment: Regardless of if you have your own non date picker templates - this file (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js) is required for the date pickers standard functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation about this behaviour

AngularJS MTV Meetup: Best Practices (2012/12/11)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ZhfUv0spHCY#t=1870

you can write it like this.

```
 <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="cdate.customStartDate" is-open="date_picker1.opened"  max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" class="input-md" />
```

In controller:

```
$scope.date_picker1 ={
    date: new Date(),
    opened: false;
 };
 $scope.open = function($event) {
     .....
     $scope.date_picker1.opened = true;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

#### After looking at so many answers. What worked for me is something like below:

```
$scope.datePicker = {
  date_opened:false
}
$scope.open_from = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  $scope.datePicker.date_opened = true;
};
```

#### HTML Template:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input name="date_obj_from" type="text" class="form-control" uib-
    datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="date_obj_from" is-
    open="datePicker.date_opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
    ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-
    click="open_from($event)">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
       </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

We do not have to involve $timeout fixing this issue. I mean why if someone does not need it.
I fixed this issue by changing my attribue is-open="date_opened" to is-open="datePicker.date_opened".
Always a best practice initializing key to you object.