# Multiple angular ui bootstrap datepickers with buttons

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have two datepickers that now work but I still can't get the button to work.

I implemented the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474054/angularjs-datepicker-not-opening-twice-angular-ui-version-0-11-0) but it gets rid of the button. I'd like to keep the calendar button.

How can I keep the calendar button working?

edit: to clarify, it works only for the first click

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text"
   datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"
   ng-model="report_args.start_date"
   is-open="opened1"
   ng-click = "report_args.start_date.open = true"
   max-date="maxDate"
   datepicker-options="dateOptions"
   date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
   ng-required="true"
   close-text="Close"
   class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="open($event,'opened1')">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.open = function($event, opened) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  $scope[opened] = true;
};
```

Comment: You most likely need to use the dot notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that the directive is making it's own copy of `$scope.opened1` in it's child scope.  When it first opens up, it works because it reads the value from the parent scope, but then when it is closed, the `opened1` value is updated in the child scope and now you can't modify from outside the child.

What you need to do is use the "dot" notation.

JS

```
$scope.dpOpened = {
  opened1: false,
  opened2: false
};

$scope.open = function($event, opened) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  $scope.dpOpened[opened] = true;
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text"
   datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"
   ng-model="report_args.start_date"
   is-open="dpOpened.opened1"
   ng-click = "report_args.start_date.open = true"
   max-date="maxDate"
   datepicker-options="dateOptions"
   date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
   ng-required="true"
   close-text="Close"
   class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="open($event,'opened1')">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Read this wiki entry on [Understanding Scope in AngularJs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: Your property 'status2' on the object $scope.dpOpened is misleading and not needed, please remove for future reference as it works perfectly fine without it. Cheers!